# Giving a player an item (minecraft plugin)

Tags: plugins, minecraft

my code is

```
package me.Doloro.FerretSBPlugin;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class YourMistakesHelpMe {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bruh")) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD));
        sender.sendMessage(org.bukkit.ChatColor.BLUE + "Check Your Inventory");
            return true;
        } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
        // If this hasn't happened the value of false will be returned.
        return false; 
    }

}
```

I want to to give a Diamond_Sword when the command is typed

there is no error only a {player} has used the command /bruh
, Also I am new to coding this so any help would help me a LOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it might be because you forgot the "implements CommandExecutor" after "public class YourMistakesHelpMe". I can't check it rn but idk why it wouldn't work.

```
package me.Doloro.FerretSBPlugin;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class YourMistakesHelpMe implements CommandExecutor {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bruh")) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD));
        sender.sendMessage(org.bukkit.ChatColor.BLUE + "Check Your Inventory");
            return true;
        } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
        // If this hasn't happened the value of false will be returned.
        return false; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forgot to implement the "CommandExecutor" after that everything should work. I copied the whole code and tested it and for me, everything worked. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lNVQ.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).